# Prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^2)^\frac{1}{5} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^2)^\frac{1}{5} = \infty$ by using the definition stated below.

For all $M>0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb R$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $x < N \implies f(x) > M$.

Scratchwork: If $(x^2)^\frac{1}{5} > M$, then $x > M^\frac{5}{2}$. Note that for all $N>0$, $x<-N$, so $x^2>N^2$, so$(x^2)^\frac{1}{5} > N^\frac{2}{5}$, so choose $N \in \mathbb R$ such that $N = M^\frac{5}{2}$.

Proof: For all $M>0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb R$ such that $N = M^\frac{5}{2}$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, for all $N>0$, from $x<-N$, we get $x^2>N^2$, so $x^\frac{2}{5} > N^\frac{2}{5} = M$ as required. $\square$

I have to use this method by the way. I am unsure on whether my logic in my proof is correct because I feel like I should have taken $x<N$ rather than $x<-N$ but this is how it was done in an example in my notes which I used to write this solution.

Comment: Since your $x$ is supposed to go to $-\infty$ you do not have to consider $x<N\,.$ The condition $x<-N$ looks better and you can restrict $N$ to be $>0$. Obviously $N=M^{5/2}$ does the job.

Comment: There is no requirement for $N$ to be positive so you don't have to use $-N$

Comment: @KurtG. So you are saying that I should rewrite my proof as: for all $M>0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb R$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $x < -N \implies x^2>N^2.....$

Comment: Should work. I also agree with Vasili that for this function $x\to-\infty$ is as good as $x\to+\infty$. Less opportunities to make sign errors.

Comment: You could (not "should") also rewrite it as "for all $M \in \Bbb R$, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, if $x < -M^{5/2}$, then $x^2 > M^5$ and $(x^2)^{1/5} > M$". It is not necessary to parrot the language of the definition in your proof. The definition is telling you the condition you must show, not providing a template for writing the proof.

Comment: Looking at this again, I was a little incautious with my phrasing (it only works for $M > 0$). A better proof would be "for $M \in \Bbb R$, let $N = 0$ if $M \le 0$ and $N = -M^{5/2}$ otherwise. Then in either case for $x \in \Bbb R$ with $x < N, x^2 > M^5$ and $(x^2)^{1/5} > M$".

Answer (score 0):

Let: $$t = x^2 $$

$$ x \to -∞ \implies t \to +∞$$

$$\underset{x\rightarrow－\infty}{\lim\;(x^2)^{\textstyle\frac {1}{5}}}＝\underset{t\rightarrow＋\infty}{\lim\;\sqrt[5]{t}}＝+∞$$